# Can an antenna be affected if mounted to a bull bar?

Tags: antenna, uhf

When I say 'mounted to a bull bar' I mean the antenna being metal on metal contact to the bull bar without any rubber or fiber glass keeping the materials from touching.

- Could this affect the performance of receiving and transmitting a signal?
- Does the antenna transfer current to the bull bar if there is nothing in-between?

I ask since my mounted UHF radio isn't receiving anybody long range, whereas my handheld does.

Extra info:

My Mounted UHF radio is: GME TX3520

Antenna: GME AE4702 6.6DBI UHF

Handheld radio: Wouxun KG-UV8D

Comment: I think this is a full wave end  fed antenna at UHF frequencies. The mount is not shown but I'd guess that it's like most mounts, where the shield and center conductors are isolated.  So I think  you're adding ground to an end fed, which would move the input impedance around. But I'm not sure that matters as much as being mounted low and in front of the vehicle body.  For UHF wavelength, that would be a barrier reducing your pattern.

Comment: What is a bull bar? Where is it mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can and even if it is insulated and close to the metal it can affect it. The frequencies are so high that it doesn't take much to have coupling from your antenna to the metal, like a capacitor. The less I say the better ;)
You can post a picture or diagram and I might be able to tell you a better location for it.